# Python string handling

Tags: python, file-io

I have started coding in python again, and I stumbled upon a strange behaviour: I have two strings which are exactly the same (see code below), but one of these strings is stored in a file, the other one is hardcoded. Now my program is running, but the string from the file looks completely different in the output compared to the hardcoded string. Why?

```
import sys

message = ''
message2 = 'MSH|^~\&|GHH LAB|ELAB-3|GHH OE|BLDG4|200202150930||ORU^R01|CNTRL-3456|P|2.4\r'
message2 += 'PID|||555-44-4444||EVERYWOMAN^EVE^E^^^^L|JONES|196203520|F|||153 FERNWOOD DR.^^STATESVILLE^OH^35292||(206)3345232|(206)752-121||||AC555444444||67-A4335^OH^20030520\r'
message2 += 'OBR|1|845439^GHH OE|1045813^GHH LAB|1554-5^GLUCOSE|||200202150730||||||||555-55-5555^PRIMARY^PATRICIA P^^^^MD^^LEVEL SEVEN HEALTHCARE, INC.|||||||||F||||||444-44-4444^HIPPOCRATES^HOWARD H^^^^MD\r'
message2 += 'OBX|1|SN|1554-5^GLUCOSE^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F'
for line in sys.stdin:
    message += line[:-1]

print message
print '\n\n'
print "New message:\n\n"
print message2
```

Output:

```
MSH|^~\&|GHH LAB|ELAB-3|GHH OE|BLDG4|200202150930||ORU^R01|CNTRL-3456|P|2.4
PID|||555-44-4444||EVERYWOMAN^EVE^E^^^^L|JONES|196203520|F|||153 FERNWOOD DR.^^STATESVILLE^OH^35292||(206)3345232|(206)752-121||||AC555444444||67-A4335^OH^20030520
OBR|1|845439^GHH OE|1045813^GHH LAB|1554-5^GLUCOSE|||200202150730||||||||555-55-5555^PRIMARY^PATRICIA P^^^^MD^^LEVEL SEVEN HEALTHCARE, INC.|||||||||F||||||444-44-4444^HIPPOCRATES^HOWARD H^^^^MD
OBX|1|SN|1554-5^GLUCOSE^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F




New message:


OBX|1|SN|1554-5^GLUCOSE^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F55^PRIMARY^PATRICIA P^^^^MD^^LEVEL SEVEN HEALTHCARE, INC.|||||||||F||||||444-44-4444^HIPPOCRATES^HOWARD H^^^^MD
```

My file looks like:

```
MSH|^~\&|GHH LAB|ELAB-3|GHH OE|BLDG4|200202150930||ORU^R01|CNTRL-3456|P|2.4
PID|||555-44-4444||EVERYWOMAN^EVE^E^^^^L|JONES|196203520|F|||153 FERNWOOD DR.^^STATESVILLE^OH^35292||(206)3345232|(206)752-121||||AC555444444||67-A4335^OH^20030520
OBR|1|845439^GHH OE|1045813^GHH LAB|1554-5^GLUCOSE|||200202150730||||||||555-55-5555^PRIMARY^PATRICIA P^^^^MD^^LEVEL SEVEN HEALTHCARE, INC.|||||||||F||||||444-44-4444^HIPPOCRATES^HOWARD H^^^^MD
OBX|1|SN|1554-5^GLUCOSE^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
```

Edit: Solution to my problem was: Either remove '\r' in the hardcoded message or add them in my file. But after I need them for further processing, I simply added them in my file which solved my problem.

Comment: The strings are **not** the same because your hardcoded string contains `\r` carriage returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Python reads a text file, line separators are translated from the platform default to `\n`. On Windows lines are separated with `\r\n`, but in *Python* your lines will end with `\n`.

Your hardcoded string, however, contains `\r` carriage return characters, the lines read from the file won't.

And if the last line doesn't have a line separator, you'll end up removing the last character anyway, unconditionally. Use `line.rstrip('\n')` to remove newlines, but only if present.

Whenever you think you have the same string but Python tells you something different, take a look at the output of the [`repr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) for those strings (use [`ascii()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ascii) on Python 3). You can also use the [`difflib.ndiff()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.ndiff) to get a quick indication of what might be different.

In your case, it *appears* that you are not removing (enough) newline characters, and your test message contains `\r` characters instead. That means the `message2` text will *replace itself* line by line as it won't advance to the next line. Use `\n` instead; you could even use a triple-quoted string to preserve newlines:

```
message2 = '''\
MSH|^~\&|GHH LAB|ELAB-3|GHH OE|BLDG4|200202150930||ORU^R01|CNTRL-3456|P|2.4
PID|||555-44-4444||EVERYWOMAN^EVE^E^^^^L|JONES|196203520|F|||153 FERNWOOD DR.^^STATESVILLE^OH^35292||(206)3345232|(206)752-121||||AC555444444||67-A4335^OH^20030520
OBR|1|845439^GHH OE|1045813^GHH LAB|1554-5^GLUCOSE|||200202150730||||||||555-55-5555^PRIMARY^PATRICIA P^^^^MD^^LEVEL SEVEN HEALTHCARE, INC.|||||||||F||||||444-44-4444^HIPPOCRATES^HOWARD H^^^^MD
OBX|1|SN|1554-5^GLUCOSE^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F'''
```

Comment: In this case I want to keep the '\r' for further handling, but I did not see that in message2 there were '\r', too. But with adding '\r' in my text file everything works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the file properly, not via stdin, to avoid control-characters messing with it:

```
import sys

message = ''
message2 = 'MSH|^~\&|GHH LAB|ELAB-3|GHH OE|BLDG4|200202150930||ORU^R01|CNTRL-3456|P|2.4\r'
message2 += 'PID|||555-44-4444||EVERYWOMAN^EVE^E^^^^L|JONES|196203520|F|||153 FERNWOOD DR.^^STATESVILLE^OH^35292||(206)3345232|(206)752-121||||AC555444444||67-A4335^OH^20030520\r'
message2 += 'OBR|1|845439^GHH OE|1045813^GHH LAB|1554-5^GLUCOSE|||200202150730||||||||555-55-5555^PRIMARY^PATRICIA P^^^^MD^^LEVEL SEVEN HEALTHCARE, INC.|||||||||F||||||444-44-4444^HIPPOCRATES^HOWARD H^^^^MD\r'
message2 += 'OBX|1|SN|1554-5^GLUCOSE^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F'

with open("my_file.txt","r") as my_file:
  for line in my_file:
    message += line

print message
print '\n\n'
print "New message:\n\n"
print message2
```